# Spring Sleuth Logback Integration logs not displaying the service name

Tags: logstash, logback, microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth

In my microservice i have added spring -sleuth 1.2.1 and i have received the logs as i expected, which is shown in below

2017-08-16 09:58:51.864  INFO [microServiceName,9434118b965d573e,9434118b965d573e,true] 1328 --- [io-8081-exec-10] com.cibc.icap.MyController       : Eligible for Vote

As per my requirement I need to pass the logs from my application to logstash server so i have created logback.xml and added dependency logstash-logback-encoder-4.5.1 and added the appender in logback.xml net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender my logback.xml looks like
now the logs are passing from my application to logstash but the problem is in the log I am not getting my microservice name as expected, The log looks like below after adding the logback.xml

2017-08-17 12:35:27.781  INFO [bootstrap,0e26cf339a6e69bc,0e26cf339a6e69bc,true] 4884 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] com.cibc.icap.AssessmentController

link for my logback.xml

Comment: cant able to post my logback.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `spring.application.name` to `bootstrap.yaml`. If that doesn't work just follow the example of `logback` configuration from the docs http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_json_logback_with_logstash

Comment: Awesome! So it was enough to add it to `bootstrap.yml` ? Write in the comment what exactly you did and let's mark it as answered.

Comment: Step 1: I have added logstash-logback-encoder-4.6 in my pom
Step 2: Added my microservices name in bootstrap.yml
Step3: Did logback configuration based on url what you have suggested me.   My services start working as expected. Thanks for your timely help.